# ngrx effect calls observer multiple times, but only one action is dispatched

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have been trying to get to the root of this problem for the last days, but can't seem to figure out what the problem is here.

Situation:
I am using Angular (11.2.6) and ngrx (11.0.1).

Problem:
The effect for an action (login) executes an observable (http post request) forever (sends the http post request constantly). Even when applying the rxjs operator "first" two requests are getting send to the backend. The resulting action (loginSuccess) gets dispatched only once, the request gets executed multiple times tho.

Code:
I have a login action which requires a username and password as parameters.

actions/autentication.actions.ts:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Authentication } from '../models/authentication';
import { Credentials } from '../models/credentials';

export const AuthenticationActions = {
    login: createAction("[Authentication] Login", props<Credentials>()),
    refreshLogin: createAction("[Authentication] Refresh Login", props<Authentication>()),
    loginSuccess: createAction("[Authentication] Login Success", props<Authentication>()),
    loginFailure: createAction("[Authentication] Login Failed"),
    refreshSuccess: createAction("Authentication Refresh Success", props<Authentication>()),
    refreshFailure: createAction("Authentication Refresh Failed"),
    logout: createAction("[Authentication] Logout"),
    failed: createAction("[Authentication] Failed")
}
```

models/credentials.ts:

```
export interface Credentials {
    username: string
    password: string
}
```

models/authentication.ts:

```
import { User } from "./user";

export interface Authentication {
    token: string
    refreshToken: string
    user: User
}
```

For this action I have an effect (login) that sends a login request to the backend using the authentication service. On success it should map to the login success action, on failure to the login failed action. Here is the problem with the endless loop.

effects/authentication.effects.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, exhaustMap, first, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/services/authentication.service';
import { SnackbarService } from 'src/services/snackbar.service';
import { AuthenticationActions } from '../actions/authentication.actions';
import { Authentication } from '../models/authentication';
import { Credentials } from '../models/credentials';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationAffects {

    constructor(
        private actions: Actions,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private snackbarService: SnackbarService
    ) { }

    public login = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions.pipe(
            ofType(AuthenticationActions.login),
            exhaustMap((credentials: Credentials) => {
                return this.authenticationService.login(credentials.username, credentials.password).pipe(
                    map(authentication => (AuthenticationActions.loginSuccess(authentication))),
                    catchError(() => of(AuthenticationActions.loginFailure())))
            })
        )
    )

    public loginRefresh = createEffect(() => this.actions.pipe(
        ofType(AuthenticationActions.refreshLogin),
        exhaustMap((authentication: Authentication) => {
            return this.authenticationService.refreshLogin(authentication.refreshToken).pipe(
                first(),
                map(authentication => (AuthenticationActions.refreshSuccess(authentication))),
                catchError(() => of(AuthenticationActions.logout()))
            )
        })
    ))

    public loginSuccess = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions.pipe(
            ofType(AuthenticationActions.loginSuccess),
            tap(() => {
                this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
                    let returnUrl = params.get("returnUrl")
                    if (returnUrl) {
                        this.router.navigate([returnUrl])
                    } else {
                        this.router.navigate(["/app"])
                    }
                })
            })
        ),
        { dispatch: false }
    )

    public loginFailure = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions.pipe(
            ofType(AuthenticationActions.loginFailure),
            tap(() => {
                this.snackbarService.showMessage("Login failed!")
            })
        ),
        { dispatch: false }
    )

    public logout = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions.pipe(
            ofType(AuthenticationActions.logout),
            tap(() => {
                this.router.navigate(["/login"])
            })
        ),
        { dispatch: false }
    )

}
```

services/authentication.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";
import { AppState } from "src/redux/app-state";

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

    public constructor(private http: HttpClient, private store: Store<AppState>) {}

    public login(name: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.getServiceUrl() + "login", {
            name: name,
            password: password
        })
    }

    public refreshLogin(refreshToken: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.getServiceUrl() + "refreshToken", {}, {
            headers: {
                refreshToken
            }
        })
    }

    public authenticate(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(this.getServiceUrl() + "authenticate")
    }

    public getServiceUrl(): string {
        return environment.domain + "/" +
            environment.services.authentication.uri
    }

}
```

For completion the reducer.

reducers/authentication.reducer.ts:

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AuthenticationActions } from '../actions/authentication.actions';
import { Authentication } from '../models/authentication';
import decode from 'jwt-decode'

export const initialAuthentication: Authentication = <Authentication>JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authentication")) || { refreshToken: undefined, token: undefined, user: undefined }

export const authenticationReducer = createReducer(initialAuthentication,
    on(AuthenticationActions.loginSuccess, (state, authentication) => {
        return authenticationSuccess(state, authentication)
    }),
    on(AuthenticationActions.refreshSuccess, (state, authentication) => {
        return authenticationSuccess(state, authentication)
    }),
    on(AuthenticationActions.logout, (state) => {
        localStorage.removeItem("authentication")
        return Object.assign({}, state, { token: undefined, refreshToken: undefined, user: undefined })
    })
);

function authenticationSuccess(state, authentication) {
    let authenticationState = { token: authentication.token, refreshToken: authentication.refreshToken, user: decode(authentication.token)["user"] }
    localStorage.setItem("authentication", JSON.stringify(authenticationState))
    return Object.assign({}, state, authenticationState)
}
```

I have already tried not loading the StoreDevToolsModule, which didn't impact anything at all. I am really hopeless at this point and would appreciate any input!

Edit: For clarification, the action is only dispatched ONCE one the login button click.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of that `exhuastMap` of effect.

Here you can find doc - https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/exhaustmap

So other calls are all ignored.

Comment: The problem is not that calls are ignored, the problem is that the observable is looped through endlessly (the one created from the authentication service) and doesnt terminate